# Why am I now getting a Shopify Storefront uncaught at getProductsInCollection error?

Tags: node.js, next.js, shopify, vercel, shopify-storefront-api

I have a next.js Shopify website hosted on vercel that has been building for the last couple of years.

a Few days ago we tried to update the content on it and the build started to fail.

> Error: Node.js version 14.x has reached End-of-Life. Deployments created on or after 2023-08-15 will fail to build. Please set Node.js Version to 18.x in your Project Settings to use Node.js 18.

> Error occurred prerendering page "/shop". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collectionByHandle' of undefined
> at getProductsInCollection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/542.js:217:39)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at async getStaticProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/shop.js:250:22)
> at async renderToHTML (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:386:20)
> at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:304:36
> at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)

We've updated to Node 18.x but it no longer builds locally or on vercel all the errors seem to point to an issue with the shop.

What has happened and how do I go about fixing the issue?